# web service for log files

Tags: web-services, logging

I was just wondering if there is such a thing as a web-service with API for logs?  I mean: is there a web-service with an HTTP API to send log records to?

I thought I saw a start-up in this space but I can't find any trace of it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.loggly.com/